# How to make UrlParameter.Optional {id} to accept blank values, and still work in WEB API

Tags: c#, rest, asp.net-web-api, get, routes

I have a default routing,

`Default Routing: http://localhost:4709/v1/{controller}/{id}`

and I am trying to create a new routing

`My Routing: http://localhost:4709/v1/{controller}/{id}/orders`

My Action can accept id with null value

```
[HttpGet]
public TotalOrders Get(string id)
{
  //return
}
```

How to achieve this, whenever I do this, I get No action was found on the controller 'KD' that matches the request.

Comment: What is the request you're trying to send?

Comment: Its a Get Request with or without id.

Comment: Can you provide and example of the request url you are trying to send

Comment: Also show how you configure the routes. the order in which you add them is important.

Answer (score 0):

You could define it like this, http://localhost:4709/v1/{controller}/{*others}

The '*' allows multiple '/'.
Like http://localhost:4709/v1/controller/5/orders.
So others would be a string of 5/orders. You would have to write your own little parser. (Null check, split '/', etc.)
An other way isn't possible, because optional parameters always have to be at the end.